# Debugging Yii-users authentication on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, debugging, yii, amazon-web-services, yii-extensions

I've hosted my Yii webapp on AWS. The login isn't working and redirects to the logged out homepage. Debugging on AWS is proving difficult.

My app implements Yii-users for the authentication system and the following controller acton is run for the login view:

```
    public function actionLogin()
{
    if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {

        $model=new UserLogin;

        // collect user input data
        if(isset($_POST['UserLogin'])){
            $model->attributes=$_POST['UserLogin'];
            // validate user input and redirect to previous page if valid
            if($model->validate()) {                
                $this->lastViset();
                if (Yii::app()->user->returnUrl=='/index.php'){
                    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->controller->module->returnUrl);
                } else {
                    $time = date('h:i:s A');
                    mail('my-email@gmail.com','Debugging',"BP3 $time");
                    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
                }
            }
        }
        // display the login form
        $this->render('/user/login',array('model'=>$model));

    } else {
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->controller->module->returnUrl);
    }
}
```

The code runs OK the POST data is being passed, the problem appears to be with the $model->validate() not evaluating to true. I believe this to be the case as I've followed which parts of the login action run "if($model->validate())" runs, but the code within the loop doesn't making me think it hasn't evaluated to true.

The UserLogin model is like so:

```
<?php

/**
 * LoginForm class.
 * LoginForm is the data structure for keeping
 * user login form data. It is used by the 'login' action of 'SiteController'.
 */
class UserLogin extends CFormModel
{
public $email;
public $password;
public $rememberMe;

/**
 * Declares the validation rules.
 * The rules state that username and password are required,
 * and password needs to be authenticated.
 */
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        // username and password are required
        array('email, password', 'required'),
        // rememberMe needs to be a boolean
        array('rememberMe', 'boolean'),
        // password needs to be authenticated
        array('password', 'authenticate'),
    );
}

/**
 * Declares attribute labels.
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'rememberMe'=>UserModule::t("Remember me next time"),
        'username'=>UserModule::t("email"),
        'password'=>UserModule::t("password"),
    );
}

/**
 * Authenticates the password.
 * This is the 'authenticate' validator as declared in rules().
 */
public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
{
    if(!$this->hasErrors())  // we only want to authenticate when no input errors
    {
        $identity=new UserIdentity($this->email,$this->password);
        $identity->authenticate();
        switch($identity->errorCode)
        {
            case UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE:
                $duration=$this->rememberMe ? Yii::app()->controller->module->rememberMeTime : 0;
                Yii::app()->user->login($identity,$duration);
                break;
            case UserIdentity::ERROR_EMAIL_INVALID:
                $this->addError("username",UserModule::t("Email is incorrect."));
                break;
            case UserIdentity::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID:
                $this->addError("username",UserModule::t("Username is incorrect."));
                break;
            case UserIdentity::ERROR_STATUS_NOTACTIV:
                $this->addError("status",UserModule::t("You account is not activated."));
                break;
            case UserIdentity::ERROR_STATUS_BAN:
                $this->addError("status",UserModule::t("You account is blocked."));
                break;
            case UserIdentity::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID:
                $this->addError("password",UserModule::t("Password is incorrect."));
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I don't understand what would not work with this code on AWS that works fine on a shared/local environments. I'm using the Elastic Beanstalk environment and have overridden several settings of the php.ini file with the following:

```
files:
  "/etc/php.d/project.ini" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    content: |
        error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING
        display_errors = On
        post_max_size = 32M
        enable_dl = On
```

How should I go about debugging this code on AWS? Admittedly my knowledge of Yii-users is not as good as it should be.

Comment: Do you happen to have a load balancer in front of several machines? If not, where are you storing session?

Comment: I confess ignorance - I hadn't even realised session storing would be a problem. I can see some info on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478795/aws-elastic-beanstalk-and-php-sessions I will read up on it. Thank you!

Comment: I've also got various answers to session issues in my answer history if you need. Good luck, it takes a bit to work out! :-)